# Howto filter in Report Builder using IN or OR

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to filter a series in a Reporting Services Report Chart using Report Builder (started directly from Reporting Server default Webinterface).

What I want is to filter a series on different values, originally by using an OR clause. Because this is not possible in the dialogue, I guess it was a too complicated task for the develoers to create the required logic implementing brackeds etc) I try to use the operator "IN".

I want to filter the values in my dataset like this: 
    IN('% Processor Time','Buffer cache hit ratio')

Several attempts to enter the strings into the one(!) textbox avaiable for this filter failed. Sometimes I get just NO DATA. If I just enter the strings like this:

```
% Processor Time, Buffer cache hit ratio
```

and confirm this, reopen the dialogue, the value is automatically changed to sth. like that:

```
"""% Processor Time, Buffer cache hit ratio"""
```

and after confirming this again, I get this unhandeled exception:

> 

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items2
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Common.CollectionUtil.ElementsEqual[T](ICollection`1 items1, ICollection`1 items2, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Dialogs.Controls.FilterItemControl.SaveData()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Controls.ListControlBinding.SaveData()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Controls.PropertyControl.SaveData()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Controls.PropertyDialog.OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CheckCloseDialog(Boolean closingOnly)
```

After that I just tried to use ONE argument with the IN operator, but this also does not work because it delivers just NO DATA.

`enter code here`So my question is, does anyone know a solution for filtering a dataset using OR or IN clause in Microsoft Report Builder?